# Looking for p4perl sample codes to add/delete/checkout/checkin files into/from P4 repository

Tags: perl, perforce

I know how to add/delete/checkin/checkout files using p4perl when my p4perl script and the files belong to the same p4 client. However, I don't know how to do it when the p4perl script and the files belong to different p4 clients.

I guess I need to call $p4->FetchClient() somehow. But I don't know exactly how to do it.

Below is my piece of experimental codes which can check out a file under the same p4 client.

```
use strict;
use P4; # a p4perl module

**#my $p4root = "A P4 root dir" e.g. '//projects/...'
# File '$f1' is under a different p4 client root, e.g. $p4root
#my $f1 = $ENV{HOME}.'/work/aFile_ToBe_Checkedout_From_P4.pl';**

# File '$f2' is under the same p4 client root as this tool $0 is in
my $f2 = './runANI.pl';

&showFileMode($f2);

my $p4 = new P4;
$p4->Connect() or die( "Failed to connect to Perforce Server" );
**#$p4->RunEdit($f1); # To check out file '$f1'. It does not work
#&reportP4err($p4);**
$p4->RunEdit($f2); # To check out file '$f2'. It works!!
&reportP4err($p4);

&showFileMode($f2);
exit;

sub showFileMode {
  my ($file) = @_;
  my @properties = stat($file);
  my $mode = $properties[2];
  my $modeInDecimal = $mode & 07777;
  my $modeInOctal = sprintf("%04o", $modeInDecimal);
  if($modeInOctal eq '0555') {
    print "File '$file' is checked in with a mode: $modeInOctal\n";
  }
  elsif($modeInOctal eq '0755') {
    print "File '$file' is checked out with a mode: $modeInOctal\n";
  }
}

sub reportP4err {
  my ($p4) = @_;
  if ($p4->ErrorCount()) {
    print "In report_p4_errors()\n";
    foreach my $e ($p4->Errors()) {
      print "P4 Error MSG: $e\n";
    }
    die "P4 error, exiting";
  }
}
```

A sample run:

```
% ./testP4perl.pl
File './runANI.pl' is checked in with a mode: 0555
File './runANI.pl' is checked out with a mode: 0755
```

Comment: Just to clarify: are you having trouble setting your Perforce connection information when the perl script lives in a different workspace than the files you're operating on?  If so you can set the active workspace in P4Perl.

Comment: Is there any website where there are proper tutorials of P4PERL? Either blog or video tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

If your files are in different workspaces, then just as you would switch workspaces in p4v to submit files, you would need to switch clients when using the p4perl API.

Use the `SetClient()` method to switch workspaces, for example:

```perl
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use P4;

    my $p4 = new P4;

    ## Connect with Workspace ws_1
    $p4->SetPort( "perforce:1666" );
    $p4->SetUser( "user" );
    $p4->SetClient( "ws_1" );
    $p4->Connect() or die("Failed to connect to Server ");
    my $syncedFiles_1 = $p4->RunHave("//...");

    ## Switch to Workspace ws_2
    $p4->SetClient( "ws_2" );
    my $syncedFiles_2 = $p4->RunHave("//...");
```